# NotConnectedException error in WebDriver tests running under Jenkins on Linux

Tags: firefox, maven, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

I have a WebDriver test using the FirefoxDriver that I am attempting to run as a Jenkins job.

It works fine in Windows, it also works from the command line in Linux, where my Jenkins server lives.

Unfortunately, I got the following error during executing as a Jenkins job:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms
```

The Jenkins job consists of 2 steps: a shell step that executes:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
export DISPLAY=:1
```

And then a maven package to run the test class.

Why can't I get the Jenkins job to execute Firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What finally ended up working was to create the entire Jenkins job as one step that ran shell commands:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
export DISPLAY=:1
mvn package
```

and that worked. No more NotConnectedException.

I had originally had the Jenkins job as 2 steps, shell to create virtual frame buffer and maven goal.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the job from jenkins, it runs the same test as "Jenkins" user. You need to add one more line in etc/hosts file for jenkins user like

```
your.ip.address.value jenkins
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but can you explain in more detail why this is necessary and how this would fix the problem? When I run from the Linux command line, I am logged in to the Linux host as the same user who started the Tomcat instance Jenkins is running in (not root!)